# Is there a way to automate sending a keystroke to a program when audio finished playing?

Tags: windows, audio, autohotkey

I am looking at AutoHotkey or any other solution on Windows that would allow me to automate "detecting silence" and invoke some action when that happens.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Add more songs when your audio player reaches the end of its playback queue? Detecting playback or silence might be a bit difficult with AHK. You might have more luck if you mention your audio player. Most will modify their titlebar text and mention "Playing" or the song name during playback. It might be easier to detect this change.

Comment: It is an obscure database program that allows to store and replay audio annotations attached to other data. So I want it to move on to next record when it is done replaying sound associated with current entry. I don't think it changes windows title at any point.

Comment: [This](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/32290-how-to-detect-if-a-sound-was-played/) was one of the AHK threads I found, but I'm not sure how well the programs mentioned there will work. Is there no way you can write a DB script rather than using an external program to control the playback?

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that thread too. I was worried that one of the  executables suggested was a virus, so did not go that route just yet. Unfortunately the DB system is pretty closed/proprietary and does not support scripting.